# Neo4j Cypher Single Query to WHERE variables "may" appear in different patterns

Tags: inheritance, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph of parent-children objects related by [IS_A] that may be related to each other [HAS]:
[image: Graph Example]

Assuming properties are inherited by children. I want to create a single Query that could answer ALL the Questions:
Do card tables have a base? - (l {name:'card table'})-[:IS_A*]->(m)-[:HAS]->(n)-[:IS_A*]->(o {name:'base'})
Do card tables have a leg? - (l {name:'card table'})-[:IS_A*]->(m)-[:HAS]->(o {name:'leg'})
Does furniture have a base? - (l {name:'furniture'})-[:HAS]->(n)-[:IS_A*]->(o {name:'base'})
Does furniture have a leg? - (l {name:'furniture'})-[:HAS]->(o {name:'leg'})

NOT knowing what pattern my objects will match I want to test them all at once in one Query.
This is the query that makes sense to me but does not work:

```
MATCH (l {name:'X'}), (m), (n), (o {name:'Y'})
WHERE (l)-[:IS_A*]->(m)-[:HAS]->(n)-[:IS_A*]->(o) OR (l)-[:IS_A*]->(m)-[:HAS]->(o) OR (l)-[:HAS]->(n)-[:IS_A*]->(o) OR (l)-[:HAS]->(o)
RETURN l, m, n, o
```

One by one the Where's work. BUT all together I get EVERY node and relation in my DB!

Comment: While the queries here are likely examples for the sake of asking your question, and not the real queries you're working with, I did want to recommend using labels in your real queries if you aren't doing so already. That not only prevents AllNodesScans, which are inefficient for finding anchor points to start in your graph, but allows usage of indexes for lookup, provided you have created indexes on the appropriate label/properties.

Comment: Thanks, these are just examples I use UUIDs in the real queries but should start using labels more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach may be to find, for a characteristic, all descendants, and for those descendants, all possessors. Those will be the pool of things that have that characteristic:

```
 (characteristic)<-[:IS_A*0..]-(descendent)<-[:HAS]-(possessor)
```

You can aggregate these (or use a pattern comprehension so they're in a list already)

Now, for your given item under test, all you have to do is see if it has any ancestors that are in the list of possessors.

We can use LIMIT 1 to make it quicker, since we only need to stop at the first match found.

```
MATCH (characteristic:Thing {name:$characteristic}), (thing:Thing {name:$thing})

WITH characteristic, thing, 
 [(characteristic)<-[:IS_A*0..]-(descendent)<-[:HAS]-(possessor) | possessor] as possessors

MATCH path = (thing)-[:IS_A*0..]->(ancestor)
WHERE ancestor IN possessors
RETURN ancestor
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: WOW that is super cool! This is so much faster than my query and I can return the whole path, which is ideal. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OH man I am a ding-a-ling I should ONLY RETURN l, o
IF I return m, n and m, n are NOT children of the query then I am indirectly asking for everything.

So the correct query is:
MATCH (l {name:'X'}), (m), (n), (o {name:'Y'})
WHERE (l)-[:IS_A*]->(m)-[:HAS]->(n)-[:IS_A*]->(o) OR (l)-[:IS_A*]->(m)-[:HAS]->(o) OR (l)-[:HAS]->(n)-[:IS_A*]->(o) OR (l)-[:HAS]->(o)
RETURN l, o

IF I get ANY nodes returned the answer is YES else NO